# How to update a statefulset?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a stateful set that I want to update but I get the error:

```
The StatefulSet "postgres" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'ordinals', 'template', 'updateStrategy', 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden
```

How do I update the staeful set?
I tried scaling down the pods:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
postgres-0                                    0/1     Pending            0             11m


kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/postgres-0
error: no objects passed to scale
```

I tried doing scale down on the service:

```
kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
postgres     ClusterIP   None           <none>        5432/TCP   107m

kubectl scale --replicas=0 service/postgres
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

So my question is, how do I apply changes to the `statefulSet`?

Comment: `services/postgres`. Error is saying `service/` isn't a valid resource prefix

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: the [answer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#scaling-a-statefulset) is `kubectl scale sts postgres --replicas=0`

Answer (score 2):

You've specifed that you have a statefulset to update, but not actually mentioned WHAT you want to update

StatefulSets in Kubernetes have an annoying limitation in that you can only change specified fields within them once they are created -- as the error message implies.

The only way to update a statefulset if it is one of the fields not permitted to be changed, is to delete the statefulset and create it again.

Provided the name of the statefulset doesn't change, kubernetes should reattach the same disks.

I ran into this issue when trying to change the labels and selectors on my statefulset and raised this into the Kubernetes project. (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90519 if you're interested)